# Openocd config file error: bcm2835gpio_swd_nums'

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, stm32, openocd, swd

I have a stm32 bonded directly with a raspberry pi through gpio. Now I just try to configure a openocd and write a config file:

adapter driver bcm2835gpio

bcm2835gpio_swd_nums SWCLK_PIN_HERE SWDIO_PIN_HERE
transport select swd

source [find target/stm32f0x.cfg]

bindto 0.0.0.0

init
targets
and get a error :

DEPRECATED! use 'adapter gpio swclk; adapter gpio swdio' not 'bcm2835gpio_swd_nums'
Error: illegal option for adapter gpio swclk: SWCLK_PIN_HERE
adapter gpio [

```
        do|tdi|tms|tck|trst|swdio|swdio_dir|swclk|srst|led[gpio_number]
        [-chip chip_number] [-active-high|-active-low]
        [-push-pull|-open-drain|-open-source]
```

Then I modify it as：
adapter driver bcm2835gpio

adapter gpio swclk 11
adapter gpio swdio 25

transport select swd

source [find target/stm32f0x.cfg]

bindto 0.0.0.0

init
targets

but still get error :
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : BCM2835 GPIO JTAG/SWD bitbang driver
Info : clock speed 1006 kHz
Error: Error connecting DP: cannot read IDR

I try to correct it but always fail, could someone help me ?   thanks in advance.

Comment: Most probably wrong physical connection or your target MCU is unpowered.